# Transfering a question from Ask Ubuntu to Super User

Tags: support, stackexchange, moderators

The following question is not getting any further feedback after revisions.  Also, it appears to be a - non Ubuntu related - hardware issue.  I didn't get any Ubuntu related search hits with the error messages:

[Ubuntu 12.04 System crashes right after login - Boot-Repair log included](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253185/ubuntu-12-04-system-crashes-right-after-login-boot-repair-log-included)

Can I request a moderator to transfer the question to StackExchange "Super User"?  How does this work, just send a message to a user listed as moderator?

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I actually came up with a solution to the posted problem ... myself :)  Thanks to everyone who tried to help!