# How to transfer a question through Stack Exchange Communities

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I've just earned a badge in [this popular question](https://superuser.com/q/1504821/1063603) I wrote 15 months ago in *SuperUser Community*. And it attracted me because, even after all this time and 1000 views, it stills not-answered. Thus I got that I questioned it in the wrong community, probably in AskUbuntu it wouldn't stayed so much time untouched.

So I would like to understand what is the policy over transfer questions between communities and how I could achieve it

I checked [Transfering a question from Ask Ubuntu to Super User](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6078/689894), but there's also no answers there

Comment: You can't *migrate* questions that are older than 2 months. You'll have to delete the original and re-post it here.

Comment: Isn't that the answer @muru ? Are you hoping someone will write something more in-depth about migration policy?

Comment: @Zanna not about migration policy, but more about the chances a question would be more likely to be answered here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transferring posts between communities is a lot more... complex... than you'd think.

Firstly, **unless there's migration paths opened already** (which there are not for the 'community' to use to move things to / from Ask UbuntU), migration of questions between communities requires the moderators on the origin site to intervene to moderate.

Secondly, **the older the question, usually the more it's not likely to get migrated**.  That's a decision by the origin site's mods, yes, but the mods of the destination site *can* reject the migration by closing the question.

Thirdly, **the system does not let us migrate posts that are more than 2 months old**.  (which I just confirmed by testing)  Which means your post cannot be migrated.  You'll have to delete and repost it here if you *really* want to move it to Ask Ubuntu.

---

The issue of migration not being possible aside...

Specifically for your question, you've also **already given yourself your answer** - you can do this by altering the `.desktop`'s Exec line to pass in the option you want to not prompt.

You're also **very very vague** with your question - to quote muru from that post's comment:

> "What do you mean by "manage this in the appropriate setting"?

... this means it's more likely that it'd be closed as "unclear what you're asking" here (by close voters), which would also reject the migration.

If you have every intention of wanting the post here on Ask Ubuntu, the solution is to delete (or flag for deletion) the other post on Super User, and repost here.  Keep in mind that you have an upvote on your question, so that is also a factor.